# how can i upload an image(using NodeJs) as an input to my image classifier api in flask or image classifier running at XYZ.com using upload button

Tags: node.js, api, flask

I am having hard time finding how i can upload an image to my image classifier api and do prediction on it.
in node js i copy paste many code examples but it only saves a copy of the file to an upload folder but there is no option to add the file to an api.
I am running both server( NodeJs and flask(api)) on my localhost.
Eg.I need something similar like AWS Rekognition makes us select an image and show the response.

This is the code that I copy pasted but don't know how add the api and send the image selected on the page

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
            var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
            console.log(oldpath);
            console.log('Fields', fields)
            console.log('Files', files)
            var newpath = 'C:/Users/Pratham Nishad/Desktop/' + 
files.filetoupload.name;
            fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
                res.end();
            });
        });
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">');
        res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
        res.write('<input type="submit">');
        res.write('</form>');
        return res.end();
    }
}).listen(4000);
```

What I want- Lets say that I have an Image Classifier ready to make classify image at XYZ.com and I want to make user select an image(**PROBLEM HERE**) from his/her storage and process it and post the result.
All the tutorial that i watched just selects the image from one location and paste it to destination location, no information how the image classifier running at XYZ.com will get the image.

Comment: Please share what have you done so far.

Comment: NodeJs file(adds text data to an api)

Comment: I mean share your code and clarify where you stuck. By this way we can help you. Thank you.

Comment: Samim Hakimi I just want to know what is the process of sending image file to an api which predict the class of an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out multer package on npm:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

As requested I'll demonstrate how I actually used this tool.

> Front-end Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the "Choose File" button to upload a file:</p>

<form action="xyz.com" method="post">
  <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

> Backend Code:

```
const multer = require('multer');

//Multer DiskStorage Config
const diskStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: 'path/to/your/desired/folder',
    filename: (req, file, call_back) => {

        //Prepend date to the filename
       //or anything that can uniquely identify the file
       //so it won't get overwritten by the new ones
        call_back(null, Date.now() + '_' + file.originalname);
    }

});

//Create Multer Instance
const upload = multer({ storage: diskStorage });



//Upload picture
router.post('/uploadpic', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
res.status(200);
    });
```

After the file has been saved, you can use it with the image classifier.

You are really free to create your own file structure. There are no specific constraints or rules that you have to follow.

Comment: Look it might sound stupid to you. I have confusion over what happens when we select the Image- What I think from all the tutorial is that It only stores the Image to an Upload folder and what happens after that is a mystery to me.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to upload it to the AWS Rekognition API?

Comment: AvivLo I really appreciate your help when you go to Rekognition page there is an upload button for image from which the visitor selects the image and then Rekognizer process the image.(I want the functionality of that button). And AWS Rekognizer was just a bad example [link](https://imagga.com/auto-tagging-demo) thats a better example I have the classifier and upload of file is mystery.

Comment: Ah ok. So are you asking for the client-side code? I just updated the answer.

Comment: AvivLo again I really appreciate your reply.Lets say you made XYZ.com you have image classifier and you have upload form as well on the page. I the user visits the XYZ.com and selects an image. STOP HERE PROBLEM IS HERE how the image selected by me the user is received by you and now where is the upload folder and where is the image. I am so naive.

Comment: Alright. So if you are the user of my website, which for example is xyz.com; and I own the upload form and the image classifier.  When you select the file, you're basically the part of code at UPDATE2 above. When you click the button and the front end sends the image to the back end, the code in UPDATE above will be executed. The upload folder will be on the server and the image will be in the upload folder. How the image classifier will process it is another story.

Comment: AvivLo That somewhat clears my doubt  I will do some research. Can you shed some light on the file structure on the server. As I am using node js I am new to this technology and only run program on local host so I have no idea about it. Can I use netlify to host

Comment: I have just updated my answer. Yes, you should be able to use Netify to host.

Comment: Please remove the UPDATEs. It is not useful to have such breaks in your answer. We have edit history to see what was added.